# snap: unable to remove old versions of apps

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, snap

I found that i have 14 firefox versions on my disk taking up 4.2GB.
There are more than 2 versions for core, code and chrome too.

I used `sudo snap list firefox --all` but it only listed two versions for firefox.
[image: snap firefox]
[image: firefoxes on disk]

I tried `sudo snap set system refresh.retain=2` but that doesn't clean up existing versions.

How should i remove those old firefox versions?

If i use for example `sudo snap remove firefox --revision 3799`, it would complain `revision 3799 of snap "firefox" is not installed`.

Also I noticed that snap is not detecting those newer versions (39**) as well.

Is this a bug in snap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone with similar problem, looks like this is a known bug in snap and will be fixed in 2.62. Check out the thread [here](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/unable-to-remove-old-versions-of-apps/39354/7).